Relationship between Variance and Consistency?
This is something I have been struggling to understand. Our prof told us that a consistent estimator has $0$ variance as $n$ becomes large. Even though this intuitively makes sense, I don't understand why this - why does consistency imply $0$ variance? My source of confusion stems from the actual definition of consistency.
An estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ is consistent for the parameter $\theta$ if:
$$\hat{\theta}_n \xrightarrow{p} \theta \text{ as } n \to \infty$$
In this formula, I see no mention of variance.
I brought this up with my prof, and my prof suggested to bridge the gap using the bias-variance decomposition and the mean squared convergence. I tried to do some of these mathematical gymnastics.
Part 1: The bias-variance decomposition :
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = [E(\hat{\theta}_n) - \theta]^2 + Var(\hat{\theta}_n)$$
Definition of variance:
$$Var(\hat{\theta}_n) = E[(\hat{\theta}_n - E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2]$$
Expand the squared term:
$$Var(\hat{\theta}_n) = E[\hat{\theta}_n^2 - 2\hat{\theta}_n E(\hat{\theta}_n) + (E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2]$$
Use the linearity of expectation:
$$Var(\hat{\theta}_n) = E[\hat{\theta}_n^2] - 2E(\hat{\theta}_n)E(\hat{\theta}_n) + (E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2$$
$$Var(\hat{\theta}_n) = E[\hat{\theta}_n^2] - (E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2$$
Left hand side of  original equation:
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2]$$
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = E[\hat{\theta}_n^2 - 2\hat{\theta}_n\theta + \theta^2]$$
Use the linearity of expectation:
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = E[\hat{\theta}_n^2] - 2\theta E(\hat{\theta}_n) + \theta^2$$
Now, add and subtract $(E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2$ (This step I got from my textbook):
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = E[\hat{\theta}_n^2] - (E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2 + (E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2 - 2\theta E(\hat{\theta}_n) + \theta^2$$
I can see the variance formula contained in this:
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = Var(\hat{\theta}_n) + (E(\hat{\theta}_n))^2 - 2\theta E(\hat{\theta}_n) + \theta^2$$
Factor the last three terms:
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = Var(\hat{\theta}_n) + (E(\hat{\theta}_n) - \theta)^2$$
Part 2: Mean Squared Convergence
I was given the following definition for Mean Squared Convergence:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = 0$$
From here, I can recognize the above work used in the bias-variance decomposition:
$$E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = [E(\hat{\theta}_n) - \theta]^2 + Var(\hat{\theta}_n)$$
Now, I think I am starting to understand the idea. In effect, for a consistent estimator, as $n \to \infty$, BOTH the bias and variance MUST approach zero:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} [E(\hat{\theta}_n) - \theta]^2 = 0$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} Var(\hat{\theta}_n) = 0$$
So, while the basic definition of consistency doesn't explicitly mention variance, the requirement that $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges in probability to $\theta$ implies that its variance must approach zero. If the variance didn't approach zero, there would always be some "spread" in the distribution of $\hat{\theta}_n$ around $\theta$, preventing convergence in probability.
Did I get the right idea?

If you assume mean-square convergence of your estimator $\hat\theta_n$, that is :
$$\hat\theta_n\stackrel{L^2}{\to}\theta \text{ as } n \to \infty, $$
then yes, you have correctly shown that it implies that both the bias and variance of $\theta_n$ must converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.
However, the usual definition of consistency only assumes convergence in probability (weak consistency) or almost surely (strong consistency), that is :
$$\hat\theta_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\theta\ \text{ or }\ \hat\theta_n\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}\theta \text{ as } n \to \infty, $$
now if we merely assume that $\hat\theta_n$ is a weakly consistent estimator of $\theta$, then it is possible that neither the variance, nor the bias converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ !
Consider the following example from Wikipedia : fix $\theta\in\mathbb R$ as the value we want to estimate, let $\delta >0$ be any positive number and for all $n\in\mathbb N$ let
\begin{cases}\mathbb P(\hat\theta_n = \theta) &= 1 - 1/n,\\
\mathbb P(\hat\theta_n = n\delta+\theta)&= 1/n. \end{cases}
It is easy to check that $\hat\theta_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\theta$ yet its bias is given by $\mathbb E[\hat\theta_n - \theta] = \delta $ for all $n$, which does not converge to $0$, while its variance is equal to
$$ \mathbb E\big[(\hat\theta_n - \mathbb E[\hat\theta_n])^2\big] = \left(1-\frac1n\right)\delta^2 + \frac1n (n-1)^2\delta^2 = \left(1-\frac1n\right)n\delta^2, $$
which diverges as $n\to\infty$.
